# How to make a Ubuntu print server?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, printer, ubuntu-10.10

I am using Intel Core i3 Windows XP as OS, and I have installed Ubuntu in VMware.

Am planning to make the ubuntu as the print server which could run in the VMware and give the privilege to users to print. Could you assist me by giving the steps to do so.

Comment: Could you explain the users and current networking for the print server; i.e. how many clients will connect and how? Right now it just sounds like you're running a print server host in VMware and the XP is the client.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to keep the system running 24/7? I suggest for this purpose it's better to either run just Ubuntu without the hassle of configuring system on vmware for printer sharing or share printers though your XP system.

What kind of printers (network, usb, scsi...) are you using and for what other tasks are you intending to use your Ubuntu installed on vmware?
And what users will be suing them? Local users using just that machine or network users? Please give more info is it's possible.

It's simply too complicated to be using a system installed on vmware just for printer sharing. Also, there are some minor problems with usb support in vmware and printer support in Ubuntu. Using cups printing system generally does the job but not in all cases.